# how to get plist data into table view in a alphabatic order

Tags: ios

I'm using this code to load some data from a plist file:

```
self.title =@"Data"; 
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data"ofType:@"plist"]; 
dict =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:path]; 
sortedCountries =[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Name"]];
```

And I'm showing the information in tableView:

```
cell.textLabel.text = [sortedCountries objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

It is showing the plist elements correctly but I need to display the data in Alphabetic order.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
sortedCountries =[[NSArray alloc]initWithArray:[dict objectForKey:@"Name"]];
```

for this:

```
NSArray *array = [dict objectForKey:@"Name"];
sortedCountries = [array sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
```

Comment: Or you could use this method: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/sortedArrayUsingComparator: